# Getting BindingResults to show me the field associated with an error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web-applications

I'm trying to write an integration test for a Spring WebApp I'm working on.  At one point during the process I'm pulling the list of errors out of a `BindingResult` using this code:

```
    BindingResult checkMe = (BindingResult)mv.getModelMap().get("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.module");
    assertEquals(1, check.getErrorCount());

    //Check to make sure it is the right field that errored, and had the right error.
    if(check.hasErrors()){

        List<ObjectError> errors = checkMe.getAllErrors();
        assertEquals(1, errors.size());
        ObjectError tester = errors.get(0); 
        assertEquals("Range", tester.getCode());
        assertEquals("must be between 0 and 365", tester.getDefaultMessage());          

    }
```

I want to add a line that will assert that the field that is throwing the error is in fact "daysToComplete".  I know the information is in there somewhere because `checkMe.getAllErrors().toString()` returns:

```
[Field error in object 'module' on field 'daysToComplete': rejected value [1000]; codes [Range.module.daysToComplete,Range.daysToComplete,Range.int,Range]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [module.daysToComplete,daysToComplete]; arguments []; default message [daysToComplete],365,0]; default message [must be between 0 and 365]]
```

How do I just get the field itself?  I've looked through the documentation and asked google but nothing seems to come up...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your ObjectError is likely an instance of FieldError, which extends ObjectError. The FieldError should have a getField() method on it, which will tell you the name. Try the following (untested):

```
if (check.hasErrors()){

    List<ObjectError> errors = checkMe.getAllErrors();
    assertEquals(1, errors.size());

    FieldError tester = null;
    if (errors.get(0) instanceof FieldError) {
        tester = errors.get(0);
    } else {
        assertFail("Wrong binding result error type.");
    }

    assertEquals("daysToComplete", tester.getField());
    assertEquals("Range", tester.getCode());
    assertEquals("must be between 0 and 365", tester.getDefaultMessage());          
}
```

Comment: FieldError has not method getField()

Comment: @gstackoverflow it's true, but remember this answer is from 2013. Seems like a cast is needed now, see jefmaus' answer (a few pixels down). I just tried it myself and it works: `((FieldError) bindingResult.getAllErrors().get(0)).getField()`. `FieldError` extends `ObjectError`, the former is the one with method `getField()`

Answer (score 5):

```
public String nameMethod(@ModelAttribute Client client, BindingResult result) {
   for (ObjectError error : result.getAllErrors()) { // 1.
       String fieldErrors = ((FieldError) error).getField(); // 2.
       System.out.println(fieldErrors);
   }
}
```

1. Get all the errors obtained from BindingResult
2. Get the name of the field that produced the binding error.

Now it is possible to return the error to the user and tell him which field he should verify.

Greetings.

Comment: it wouldn't be bad to write some explanation about your code.